# Show that, for square matrices $A$ and $B$, $A+B=AB$ implies $AB=BA$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n$-by-$n$ real matrices such that $A+B = AB$.
>   How do I prove that $AB= BA$?

I have tried using the trace function on $A+B-AB$. But I could not get any Ideas.
Kindly provide me with hints.

Comment: I want to remark that, for a vector space $V$ over a field $K$ and for two $K$-linear operators $A,B: V\to V$ such that $A+B=A\circ B$, if $V$ is finite-dimensional over $K$, then $A$ and $B$ commute (i.e., $A\circ B=B\circ A$).  However, the result does not hold if $V$ is infinite-dimensional over $K$.

Comment: Take, for example, $V$ to be the vector space of infinite sequences $\mathbf{x}:=\left(x_i\right)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}}$ of elements $x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots\in K$.  For each $\mathbf{x}:=\left(x_i\right)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}}\in V$, define 
$$A(\mathbf{x}):=\left(x_1-x_2,x_2-x_3,x_3-x_4,x_4-x_5,x_5-x_6,\ldots\right)$$ and $$B(\mathbf{x}):=\left(x_1,x_2-x_1,x_3-x_2,x_4-x_3,x_5-x_4,\ldots\right)\,.$$

Comment: Then, for every $\mathbf{x}:=(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}}$ in $V$,
$$(A+B)(\mathbf{x})=\left(2x_1-x_2,2x_2-x_1-x_3,2x_3-x_2-x_4,\ldots\right)$$
and
$$(A\circ B)(\mathbf{x})=A\left(x_1,x_2-x_1,x_3-x_2,\ldots\right)=\left(2x_1-x_2,2x_2-x_1-x_3,2x_3-x_2-x_4,\ldots\right)\,,$$
but
$$(B\circ A)(\mathbf{x})=B\left(x_1-x_2,x_2-x_3,x_3-x_4,\ldots\right)=\left(x_1-x_2,2x_2-x_1-x_3,2x_3-x_2-x_4,\ldots\right)\,.$$  Thus, $$A+B=A\circ B\text{ but }A\circ B\neq B\circ A\,.$$

Comment: Thanks for your insight. It is very useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$A+B=AB$ is equivalent to $(I-A)(I-B)=I$. As $I-A$ and $I-B$ are square, this implies $(I-B)(I-A)=I$, etc.

Comment: @tony then mark it as answered.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: @user25959 You cannot accept an answer before 15 min. after the post.